# Partial dependence plot (PDPbox) error on lightGBM model: "wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies "

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I have a snippet of code like this

```
import lightgbm as lgb
from pdpbox import pdp, get_dataset, info_plots
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#load some data
df = sns.load_dataset("iris")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, train_size=0.80)
lgd_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)
params={ "objective": "multiclass",
            "num_class": 3,}
clf = lgb.train(params, d_train)
#plot partial dependence
pdp_dist = pdp.pdp_isolate(
            model=clf, dataset=X_train, model_features=X_train.columns, feature='petal_width'
        )
pdp.pdp_plot(pdp_dist, 'petal_width')
```

This probably has something to do with predict output is probably for the 3 iris class, but I don't know how to fix it.

If I use the other lightGBM syntax of lgb.LGBMClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train), then it keeps return an error

> [LightGBM] [Fatal] Do not support special JSON characters in feature name.

despite my data has absolutely no special characters. Any way to get around it? Thanks1

Answer (score 3):

Your error message will be gone if you switch to `sklearn` API of `lightgbm`. This is the right API as suggested in the [docs](https://pdpbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pdp_isolate.html):

> model: a fitted ***sklearn*** model

**Proof**

```
import lightgbm as lgb
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from pdpbox import pdp, get_dataset, info_plots

#load some data
df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
X = df.iloc[:,:4]
y , mapping = pd.factorize(df["species"])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.80)

lgd_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)
params={ "objective": "multiclass",
            "num_class": 3,}

clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier() # <-- Choose sklearn API !!!
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

pdp_dist = pdp.pdp_isolate(model=clf, dataset=X_train
                           , model_features=X_train.columns
                           , feature='petal_width')
pdp.pdp_plot(pdp_dist, 'petal_width');
```

[image]

As far as your other error is concerned, I cannot reproduce it on my machine with `lightgbm v. 2.3.1` installed from `conda-forge`.

So, I believe you have 2 courses of action:

- install a lightgbm version that doesn't have such an issue
- or replace all non-alphanumeric characters in the column names:

```
X_train.columns = ["".join (c if c.isalnum() else "_" for c in str(x)) for x in X_train.columns]
```

as suggested [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2019/discussion/120344)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code at the beginning of your work:

```
import re
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x:re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9_]+', '', x))
```